# pip install of psycopg2 says no section error 'build_ext'

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine. All the relevant packages are installed (python-dev, libpq-dev, etc...)

When I run pip install psycopg2 with the virtualenv activated I get the following output. It appears to be a path traversal problem. The setup.cfg clearly has a [build_ext] section at the very top, so I don't think setup.py is finding the correct file. Any help?

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/build/psycopg2/setup.py", line 459, in <module>
        use_pydatetime  = int(parser.get('build_ext', 'use_pydatetime'))
      File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 798, in get
        d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
      File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 1154, in _unify_values
        raise NoSectionError(section)
    configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'build_ext'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/build/psycopg2/setup.py", line 459, in <module>

    use_pydatetime  = int(parser.get('build_ext', 'use_pydatetime'))

  File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 798, in get

    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)

  File "/home/vagrant/outland_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 1154, in _unify_values

    raise NoSectionError(section)

configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'build_ext'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/vagrant/outland_env/build/psycopg2
Storing complete log in /tmp/tmpoeLbaP
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps, but I simply had to cd into the downloaded install directory where setup.py lived.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I tried an older version `psycopg2==2.3.3` and that doesn't have the problem.

I noticed I also had to remove the `build/psycopg2` directory before I could pip install the new version.

Here's what I did from inside my virtualenv:

```
rm -rf build/psycopg2
bin/pip install psycopg2==2.3.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and at least in my case the reason appears to be that we have a weird configparser version installed on our server, viz., a buggy version of the configparser Python 3 backport. (I do prefer this greatly improved Python 3 version; I was just surprised to find it installed on our system.)

The (already resolved) bug [is explained here](https://bitbucket.org/ambv/configparser/issue/4).

In short, the `setup.py` of the current psycopg2 loads a file `setup.cfg` thus:

```
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('setup.cfg')
```

The `read` method can take a singe file name of a list of file names. In this case, the file name is specified as bytestring (a.k.a. string in Python 2) if the file is run under Python 2. The backport, however, used to test whether the first parameter to `read` is an instance of `unicode` rather than `basestring`, so that it handled each letter as separate file. Due to the intended override mechanism, it fails silently if a file can’t be found, and we ended up with an empty config.

The solution is of course to upgrade to the current version of the Python 3 backport or to use the Python 2.7 version (but the Python 3 version is a lot cooler).